# Point constraint in R piecewise regression

Tags: r, regression, lm, piecewise

I am trying to fit a piecewise regression for this dataset. I know we do not have a linear relation between the dependent and independent variable but my real world application requires me to model the data as a lm segmented regression.

Here is my code with description of the steps

bond_data <- data.frame(
yield_change = c(-1.2,-0.9,-1.8,-1.4,-1.8,-2.1,-2.3,-2.1,-2.5,-2.2,-2.4,-2.5,-2.4,-2.4,
-3.0,-2.6,-5.1,-4.8,-4.9,-5.0,-5.0,-6.2,-6.1,-6.3,-5.0,-5.0),
maturity =c(10.2795,10.8603,11.7753,12.3562,12.5205,13.3589,13.8630,14.2822,14.3589,15.3589,
15.8630,16.778,17.3616,17.8658,18.3616,21.8685,22.5288,23.8685,24.3644,25.3671,
26.8712,27.8712,28.8712,29.8740,44.3781,49.3836))

The bond_data Dataframe contains these two vectors stated above.

```
#Defining lm model & segmented modelmodel <- lm(yield_change~maturity, data = bond_data)

segmented.model <- segmented(model,seg.Z=~maturity,psi = list(maturity = c(15,20,30)),fixed.psi = c(15,20,30),control = seg.control(it.max = 0, n.boot = 50))


xp <- c(min(bond_data$maturity), segmented.model$psi[,"Est."], max(bond_data$maturity))
new_data <- data.frame(xp)
colnames(new_data) <- "maturity"
o <- segmented.model

new_data$dummy1 <- pmax(new_data$maturity - o$psi[1,2], 0)
new_data$dummy2 <- pmax(new_data$maturity - o$psi[2,2], 0)
new_data$dummy3 <- pmax(new_data$maturity - o$psi[3,2], 0)
new_data$dummy4 <-I(new_data$maturity > o$psi[1,2]) * coef(o)[3]
new_data$dummy5 <-I(new_data$maturity > o$psi[2,2]) * coef(o)[4]
new_data$dummy6 <-I(new_data$maturity > o$psi[3,2]) * coef(o)[5]
names(new_data)[-1] <- names(model.frame(o))[-c(1,2)]

yp <- predict(segmented.model,new_data)
plot(bond_data$maturity,bond_data$yield_change, pch=16, col="blue",ylim = c(-8,0))
lines(xp,yp)
```

I get the following image

[Plot of actual values in blue points and pred line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvlUQ.png)

I am trying to get the first segment start at the point(maturity = 10, yield_change = 0)

One thing to note is that all my breakpoints have fixed x positions and no estimates are made so when I run segmented.model$psi my initial values are the same as my estimates (15,20 and 30) and all my st.err are zero.

How would I go about making my prediction line start at the point(maturity = 10, yield_change = 0)? I appreciate any help!

I have tried doing the following:

```
model <- lm(I(yield_change-0)~I(maturity-10), data = bond_data) 

segmented.model <- segmented(model,seg.Z=~maturity,psi = list(maturity =                        c(15,20,30)),fixed.psi = c(15,20,30), control = seg.control(it.max = 0, n.boot = 50))

#But by running the previous line I get the error (object maturity not recognised).

#By running:

segmented.model <- segmented(model,seg.Z=~I(maturity-10),psi = list(I(maturity-10) =                        c(15,20,30)),fixed.psi = c(15,20,30), control = seg.control(it.max = 0, n.boot = 50))

I get this error:

Error: unexpected '=' in "segmented.model <- segmented(model,seg.Z=~I(maturity-10),psi = list(I(maturity-10) ="
```

I do not think I am using the correct method to solve my problem...

Comment: I imagine that if I constrain the prediction model to pass through (10,0) well all the other breakpoints will adjust?

Comment: That would be what I am looking for, but I am unsure whether the first point (at maturity at 10 year) can be considered as a breakpoint due to it being the beginning of the first line. But if it can be a breakpoint I not only want to fix it at x = 10 but also at y = 0...